# Embeding feed into website for posting to Wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

Using javascript, how do I embed the wall post feed into my webpage instead of having it popup? I have played around with adding 'display:...' when calling the API. No luck tho. How do I get it fixed to my page instead of appearing as a popup? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a Facebook page's wall feed, you can use the like box social plugin.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/, Ensure you have "Show stream" checked.  You can even disable the header, disable the faces, and set the height and width to your liking.

Happy coding!